# Why WinDBG is not loading modules?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, driver, windbg, debug-symbols

I'm new to driver development and now i try to run debugger on Virtual machine using VisualDDK. But VisualDDK cannot load any module while starting debug session with pack of messages `.Unable to add module at XXXXXXXX`. This are results of command executing in Visual DDK debug console https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2326286/vddkrep.txt.
When i try to run WinDBG from Virtual Machine Monitor the debug session starts without such errors.
I thought that the problem is in the symbol path parameter but now clear to me that it's not - both WinDBG and VisualDDK console show the same `.sympath` value. 
Host computer works with

```
    Win7 home basic x64 
    VisualDDK 1.5.6 
    VirtualBox 4.2 
    VisualStudio 2010 Pro
    WDK build 7600
```

VM is Win7 x86 Ultimate.

I've already broken my head thinking what i've done wrong. Please, give me advice where should i search a key to this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think its problem for loading the driver. Probably, the debugger did not able to find the symbols correctly.

This symbol path doesn't look good.

```
C:\SYMBOLS.NET\_studiocache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;
C:\SYMBOLS.NET\_studiocache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols
```

There is missing `srv*` at the beginning. Try this

```
srv*C:\SYMBOLS.NET\_studiocache\MicrosoftPublicSymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. All possible symbol paths i set in Visual studio and Visual DDK take not effect - debugger still "**Unable to add module at XXXXXXXX**". I think that _adding module_ is different to _loading symbol for module_, and i cannot find explanation for this error message.